# Juntar nomes duplicados em uma linha só

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Estou com essa planilha:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho na planilha o cliente ELISMAR CARLOS RODRIGUES DA MATA, que fez 3 compras, duas na data 10/08/2014 e uma na data 20/08/2014. O que eu preciso é consolidar todos os pagamentos da mesma data na mesma linha, ou seja, ficar assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As duas parcelas do dia 10/08/2014 foram somadas (399 + 1561,56) e consolidadas em uma linha só e a do dia 20/08/2014 permaneceu normal, por se tratar de outro dia.

Eu tentei com planilhas dinâmicas, o melhor resultado que tive foi esse:

Ela separa os pagamentos por DATA e agrupa as parcelas que foram pagas por CPF. O que já ajuda, porém, preciso que a planilha esteja no padrão acima, para usar em um código que já está pronto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você já desenvolveu algo? poste seu código ou sua fórmula para tentarmos ajuda-lo.

Comment: Não desenvolvi nada ainda. Não consegui achar uma solução.

Comment: Estou reinstalando o office aqui, assim que puder estarei tentando. Mas tente fazer algo

Comment: Tabela dinâmica ... não precisar por a mão em uma linha de código ...

Comment: Mas como faço para colocar a planilha dinâmica no padrão que está aí? e usar no meu código?

Comment: usar em qual código ? não existe nenhum código na sua pergunta

Comment: eu sei, eu quero usar essa planilha em um código, o código já está pronto, só preciso da planilha no formato padrão.

Comment: Mas então faz a mão...

Comment: esse é só um pedaço da planilha, são mais de 10.000 registros.

Answer (score 2):

Como o `gmsantos` comentou, você pode colocar em Tabela Dinâmica, para facilitar:

- Seleciona toda a tabela, com os cabeçalhos inclusive;
- Formata como tabela, marca a opção "Minha tabela tem cabeçalhos";
- Insere uma tabela dinâmica e nos dados seleciona a tabela que você
  acabou de criar;
- Para moldar a tabela, arraste NOME CLIENTE nas linhas, e VALOR REAL
  DAS PARCELAS em valores;

Vai te exibir a soma para cada cliente.

Comment: Eu fiz a tabela dinâmica, só que ela não fica no padrão.
vou editar a pergunta para ver se ajuda.

Comment: veja se agora fica mais fácil me ajudar.